# Main Ui Freezes

Tags: android, multithreading, kotlin, freeze

I am trying to blink the camera led at the different speed.

so to do this I am using seekbar to change the blinking speed.

When I first change the value of seekbar it starts blinking

```
private fun startFlashLightBlink(context: Context,blinkSpeed: Int) {

        isBlinkFlashLight=true
     flashLightBlinkThread = Thread{

                Looper.prepare()
                while (isBlinkFlashLight){
                    val blinkInterval:Long=blinkSpeed*100L
                    //getMainLooper() handler is associated "with the Looper for the current thread" ... which is currently the main(UI) thread
                    val handler = Handler()

                    var runnable:Runnable = Runnable{
                        toggleFlashLight()
                    }
                    handler.postDelayed(runnable,blinkInterval)
                }

                Looper.loop()

            }
            flashLightBlinkThread?.start()

    }
```

**But it freezes the main UI so now I am not able to change the value using seekbar And gets ANR message.** 
What should I do? I can't use the asynkTask. 
Service is also not a good option. I think.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try not using the separate Thread and Looper. Handler is enough for what you want to do. Cycle it like this:

```
private static final long POST_DELAY = 100;
private final Handler handler = new Handler();
private final Runnable cycleRunnable = new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        if (isCycling) {
            // make your cycle body here
            handler.postDelayed(cycleRunnable, POST_DELAY);
        }
    }
};

private boolean isCycling = false;

public void startCycle() {
    if (!isCycling) {
        isCycling = true;
        handler.postDelayed(cycleRunnable, POST_DELAY);
    }
}

public void stopCycle() {
    if (isCycling) {
        isCycling = false;
        handler.removeCallbacks(cycleRunnable);
    }
}
```

Comment: There is error at line 6 i.e.             handler.postDelayed(cycleRunnable, POST_DELAY); cycleRunnable variable placement is wrong. It can't inside.

Comment: Ye, sure. Fixed it

Comment: it is running only one time but I want to run infinite time till user does not cancel it.

Comment: I don't know your code is working fine in java but not in kotlin. By the way thanks a lot.